# How to use Room @Query with SQL file?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I got a SQL file in assets/resources how to use it to replace the below query?

```
@Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user")
fun loadFullName(): List<NameTuple>
```

I would like to continue and have compile-time validations for the query.